# Matching people with similar names: R

Tags: r, join, matching

**I am working in R**

My data has 500,000 rows in, but small example is used here.

I have some data for staff working in schools. Some people work in one school, some two, some three etc. Each school they work in is a row of data.

Schools do not always record the first names the same for an individual. e.g. one school records as Will, another William.

I also have this assumption: for an individual working in more than one school, their second name and date of birth is always recorded the same in each school.

Based on the similarity of their first name, I want a way of identifying the people who are likely to the same person, and then allocate them an id.

There will be some sort of cut off e.g. greg and griffin are likely to not be the same person, even though they share the same first 2 letters.

**sample data:**

```
data_current <- data.frame(first_name = c("will", "william", "william", "laura", "jessica", "jessicalouise", "james", "greg", "griffin"), 
                           last_name = c("smith", "smith", "smith", "maxwell", "maxwell", "maxwell", "lead", "jones", "jones"),
                           date_of_birth = c("2000-01-02","2000-01-02", "2000-01-02", "2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-02","1999-01-02","2004-01-02","2004-01-02"), 
                           school_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

| first_name | second_name | date_of_birth | school_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| will | smith | 2000-01-02 | 1 |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 2 |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 3 |
| laura | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 4 |
| jessica | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 5 |
| jessicalouise | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 6 |
| james | lead | 1999-01-02 | 7 |
| greg | jones | 2004-01-02 | 8 |
| griffin | jones | 2004-01-02 | 9 |

**desired data:**

It is likely that the first three people are the same person, so are allocated the same person_id, and so on...

```
data_desired <- data.frame(first_name = c("will", "william", "william", "laura", "jessica", "jessicalouise", "james", "greg", "griffin"), 
                           last_name = c("smith", "smith", "smith", "maxwell", "maxwell", "maxwell", "lead", "jones", "jones"),
                           date_of_birth = c("2000-01-02","2000-01-02", "2000-01-02", "2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-02","1999-01-02","2004-01-02","2004-01-02"), 
                           school_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                           person_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

| first_name | second_name | date_of_birth | school_id | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| will | smith | 2000-01-02 | 1 | 1 |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 2 | 1 |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 3 | 1 |
| laura | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 4 | 2 |
| jessica | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 5 | 3 |
| jessicalouise | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 6 | 3 |
| james | lead | 1999-01-02 | 7 | 4 |
| greg | jones | 2004-01-02 | 8 | 5 |
| griffin | jones | 2004-01-02 | 9 | 6 |

Does anyone have an suggestions of how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at `adist`. It computes approximate string distances. But it gets very tricky for some similarities, which might only be differentiable by look up table, e.g. "gr"eg and "gr"iffin jones.

Comment: A very simple way to do this is to `paste` the surname and DOB columns together and turn it into a factor. For example `within(data_current, person_id <- as.numeric(factor(paste(second_name, date_of_birth))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility using string similarity. It works well in your example because you have complete separation in your data. However, over 500K rows you may run into some issues with this, but it could get you started:

```r
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

group_first <- function(dat, cutoff = 0.5) {
  if (n_distinct(dat) == 1) return(1)

  M <- stringsimmatrix(dat$first_name, dat$first_name, method = "cosine", q = 2)
  l <- unique(lapply(seq_len(nrow(M)), \(x) dat$first_name[M[x, ] > cutoff]))
  
  person_id <- map(dat$first_name, ~ which(grepl(.x, l, fixed = T))) |>
    modify_if(~ length(.x) > 1, ~ 0)
  
  return(unlist(person_id))
}

data_current |>
  mutate(person_id = group_first(pick(everything())), .by = c(date_of_birth, last_name)) |>
  # review output before running next mutate
  mutate(person_id = cur_group_id(), .by = c(date_of_birth, last_name, person_id))
```

**Output**

```
     first_name last_name date_of_birth school_id person_id
1          will     smith    2000-01-02         1         1
2       william     smith    2000-01-02         2         1
3       william     smith    2000-01-02         3         1
4         laura   maxwell    2007-01-02         4         2
5       jessica   maxwell    2007-01-02         5         3
6 jessicalouise   maxwell    2007-01-02         6         3
7         james      lead    1999-01-02         7         4
8          greg     jones    2004-01-02         8         5
9       griffin     jones    2004-01-02         9         6
```

---

**How it works**

1. Take each last name and date of birth group and compute a bigram character cosine similarity score. If this similarity score is above 0.5 (by default) then first names are grouped together.
2. It is possible that one first name might be in more than one first name grouping, if so then a zero is returned and these special cases will need further review. For example, "jess" could match to "jessica" and "jesse", but "jesse" might not necessarily match to "jessica". At this point the IDs are unique within last name and date of birth, but not overall.
3. After review in step #2 (this will be something you will need to do with a finer algorithm or manually) the IDs are then recalculated so they are distinct across individuals.

As mentioned in the comments this can be tricky for names that have similar bigrams but are not the same. These cases will be hard to distinguish. Also, since this is just a lexical comparison it likely will not work well for shortened names. For example, "Bob" short for "Robert" or "Dick" short for "Richard".

You may also consider using other string similarity measures. For example, you can specify the Jaro–Winkler similarity (`method = 'jw'`) with a weight (`p = 0.10`). This will weight first names that *start* the same ("will" versus "william"), resulting in a higher similarity score and potential separation.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Can I just clarify my understanding of point 2. With the Jessica /Jesse/Jess example, let's say one of the cosine scores for a pair within those 3 is <0.5, we would "lose" that person from the person_id group e.g. Jess and Jessica would be allocated to person_id = 1 and Jesse, who does not reach the cut off, would then be allocated person_id = 2). So when you say "review output" you mean experiment with the method e.g. jw/ cosine etc, so get the get matches we can?

Comment: @fe108 You are very welcome! I hope you find it useful. To clarify my second point: while probably rare, say you have a Jessica, Jess, and Jesse with the same last name and data of birth. When running this group through this algorithm, it is possible that it could find Jessica and Jess similar enough to assign them one ID. It could also find Jess and Jesse similar enough to assign them a second, different ID. In this case Jess has been double assigned an ID, which in real life isn't possible.

Comment: In this specific case this algorithm will return an ID of zero for Jess. If after this step you see an ID of 0 you may consider filtering them out or taking some other approach before the final mutate statement. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah ok -  is this what this bit of the code checks for:

person_id <- map(dat$first_name, ~ which(grepl(.x, l, fixed = T))) |>
    modify_if(~ length(.x) > 1, ~ 0)

So I could add a check to see if anyone has been allocated to a person_id = 0 to see if this edge case ends up occurring. 

This solution is very accurate. I have checked the allocation of our person_id against an existing person_id which uses national insurance number (aka social security number) and we are getting >99% agreement.

Comment: @fe108 I also made a minor update to the code (I put a conditional statement within the `group_first` function). This will save computation time on such a large data set by automatically assigning an ID to groups where each row is the same first name. For example, three rows of "Jane Doe" with the same DOB will not be fuzzy matched.

Comment: @fe108 Yes, specifically the `modify_if` statement is saying for those that have been found in more than one group, assign them an ID of 0. I would recommend that you take your same sample data, subset it for one specific group. Assign that subset data frame to `dat` and then go through the function line by line. This will greatly help with your understanding of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching based on a cutoff value you could also employ clustering algorithms, such as Affinity Propagation (suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups)).

I tried to put together a solution in R using the package `apcluster` below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(apcluster)

# define data
df <- tibble(first_name = c("will", "william", "william", "laura", "jessica", "jessicalouise", "james", "greg", "griffin"), 
             last_name = c("smith", "smith", "smith", "maxwell", "maxwell", "maxwell", "lead", "jones", "jones"),
             date_of_birth = c("2000-01-02","2000-01-02", "2000-01-02", "2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-02","1999-01-02","2004-01-02","2004-01-02"), 
             school_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

# define clustering function
get_exemplars <- function(s) {
  if (length(s) == 1L) return(s)
  
  sim_matrix <- stringdist::stringsimmatrix(s, s, method = "lv")
  rownames(sim_matrix) <- s
  colnames(sim_matrix) <- s
  
  clusters <- apcluster(negDistMat(r = 2), sim_matrix, details = TRUE)
  
  names(clusters@idx)
}

# cluster names and number examplars
set.seed(6)
df |> 
  mutate(exemplar = get_exemplars(first_name),
         .by = c(last_name, date_of_birth)) |> 
  mutate(person_id = consecutive_id(exemplar))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>   first_name    last_name date_of_birth school_id exemplar person_id
#>   <chr>         <chr>     <chr>             <dbl> <chr>        <int>
#> 1 will          smith     2000-01-02            1 william          1
#> 2 william       smith     2000-01-02            2 william          1
#> 3 william       smith     2000-01-02            3 william          1
#> 4 laura         maxwell   2007-01-02            4 laura            2
#> 5 jessica       maxwell   2007-01-02            5 jessica          3
#> 6 jessicalouise maxwell   2007-01-02            6 jessica          3
#> 7 james         lead      1999-01-02            7 james            4
#> 8 greg          jones     2004-01-02            8 greg             5
#> 9 griffin       jones     2004-01-02            9 griffin          6
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, I noticed that the clustering algorithm is quite unstable, so the result above has been overfitted using a certain seed value and string distance measure to illustrate the workflow. I think LMc is right in pointing out that a purely lexical approach might not get you all the way to your desired output. ChatGPT is doing quite a decent job at pointing out the remaining issues of judgment so (depending of the size of your dataset) that might be another option:

```
In summary:

    "Will" and "William" are likely the same person.
    "Laura" and "Jessica" are distinct names, and "Jessicalouise" may or may not refer to the same person.
    "Greg" and "Griffin" are likely different individuals.
```