# Matching names across two years

Tags: r, dplyr

**I am working in R**

I have 500,00 rows of data showing staff in schools from 2021 and 2022.

With support from users on here [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753130/matching-people-with-similar-names-r), I have been able to look for people who have the same FamilyName and DateofBirth within a year, but slightly different spellings of their GivenName, allocate them an id. i.e. I have identified all the individuals in a year.

You can see that some people work in more than one school (same id appears more than once).

```
dat_2021 <- data.frame(GivenName = c("william", "william", "laura", "jessica", "jessicalouise", "james", "greg", "griffin"), 
                       FamilyName = c("smith", "smith", "maxwell", "maxwell", "maxwell", "lead", "jones", "jones"),
                       DateOfBirth = c("2000-01-02", "2000-01-02", "2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-02","1999-01-02","2004-01-02","2004-01-02"), 
                       school_id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                       person_id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

| GivenName | FamilyName | DateOfBirth | school_id | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 2 | 1 |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 3 | 1 |
| laura | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 4 | 2 |
| jessica | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 5 | 3 |
| jessicalouise | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 6 | 3 |
| james | lead | 1999-01-02 | 7 | 4 |
| greg | jones | 2004-01-02 | 8 | 5 |
| griffin | jones | 2004-01-02 | 9 | 6 |

I also have data for 2022:

```
dat_2022 <- data.frame(GivenName = c("william", "wills", "laurra", "jessica", "jessicalouise", "jamie", "geoff", "brian"), 
                        FamilyName = c("smith", "smith", "maxwell", "maxwell", "maxwell", "lead", "jones", "davy"),
                        DateOfBirth = c("2000-01-02", "2000-01-02", "2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-02","1999-01-02","2004-01-02","2004-01-02"), 
                         school_id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                         person_id = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
```

We can see that some staff have kept the same name. Some staff have changed their first name spelling slightly. Some people will leave the dataset entirely. Some people have joined the dataset.

We have allocated them a person_id using the same link above. We now know who the individuals are in a year. In reality the 2022 people have person_id which is also an integer, but I have shown as a character to aid understanding that at this point, we have not matched up people from 2021 to 2022.

| GivenName | FamilyName | DateOfBirth | school_id | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 2 | a |
| wills | smith | 2000-01-02 | 3 | a |
| laurra | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 4 | b |
| jessica | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 5 | c |
| jessicalouise | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 6 | c |
| jamie | lead | 1999-01-02 | 7 | d |
| geoff | jones | 2004-01-02 | 8 | e |
| brian | jones | 2004-01-02 | 9 | f |

**I will assume that between 2021 and 2022, someone's FamilyName and DateofBirth do not  change. Their GivenName may change.**

What I would like is a way to find people with same the FamilyName and GivenName in 2021 and 2022 but with similar GivenNames. I.e. match people across years.

```
dat_2022_desired <- data.frame(GivenName = c("william", "wills", "laurra", "jessica", "jessicalouise", "jamie", "geoff", "brian"), 
                                FamilyName = c("smith", "smith", "maxwell", "maxwell", "maxwell", "lead", "jones", "davy"),
                                DateOfBirth = c("2000-01-02", "2000-01-02", "2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-02","1999-01-02","2004-01-02","2004-01-02"), 
                                 school_id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                                 person_id = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
                                 matched_id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA))
```

| GivenName | FamilyName | DateOfBirth | school_id | person_id | matched_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| william | smith | 2000-01-02 | 2 | a | 1 |
| wills | smith | 2000-01-02 | 3 | a | 1 |
| laurra | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 4 | b | 2 |
| jessica | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 5 | c | 3 |
| jessicalouise | maxwell | 2007-01-02 | 6 | c | 3 |
| jamie | lead | 1999-01-02 | 7 | d | 4 |
| geoff | jones | 2004-01-02 | 8 | e | NA |
| brian | jones | 2004-01-02 | 9 | f | NA |

matched_id will allow us to follow individuals through from 2021 to 2022. The matched_id in 2022 can be cross checked with the person_id in 2021 to find instances of the same individuals.

Note Geoff and Brian are missing a matched_id as although they share a FamilyName and DateOfBirth with people in 2021, their GivenNames are too different to be matched up with anyone in 2021.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you have an algorithm that does the approximate matching within a single year, why not combine the data for 2 years and then apply your algorithm to the combined table?

Comment: I would say a couple of things: 1. the scale of data you are working on (.5 million records), you are extremely likely to get false positives with this approach (e.g. John Smiths who were both born on the same day who have no relation to each other

Comment: 2. I would probably start with the string distance approach, then cull to the names which match. Cull those to the distinct pairs, and check those pairs manually, to make sure it's not doing something bad (e.g. Maria becoming Mario). Then use that as the basis for building your own thing, adding some custom ones as needed